# 自宅サーバーのアクセスに著しい遅延が生じる

Tags: html, wordpress

自宅サーバーを運営する上で困ったことがあり質問させていただきました。
先日、中古デスクトップを利用してWordPressブログを公開しようと試みたのですが、自宅以外の環境から接続するとアクセスに著しい時間を要し、時間帯によってはタイムアウトしてしまうとの報告を頂きました。

Cloudflareを介しているため、サーバー本体の問題であればエラーが表示されるはずなのですが、それも表示されないとの事なので原因が分からず困っております。

また、時間帯によっては遅延なくアクセスできるという点も引っかかっています。
原因を究明し早急に解決させて頂きたく、ご教授の程宜しくお願いします。

環境等の補足
・ポート開放などの必要作業は既に済ませてあるので、名前解決は済んでいます。
・サーバーにはUbuntuServer22.04を導入しています。
・サーバー本体は常時稼働しています。

Comment: 閲覧者が違うとときどき発生、ウエブサーバ上にログが残らない、ってのは典型的 DNS 解決の遅延ですのでそっちの確認から、ってことになるでしょう。静的 IP アドレス払い出し契約してますか？

Comment: ご助言に感謝します。ご助言の通り契約内容を確認したところ静的IPを設けるプランを指定していませんでした。早急に契約変更をさせていただきます。ありがとうございました。

Comment: DDNS をうまく使えば動的 IP アドレスな普通の（安価な）契約でもイケルはずです。短時間サービスが停止する（動的 IP アドレスの再リースから DDNS/DNS のレコード更新の間）のに目をつぶれればですが。 https での公開がしたいとなると静的 IP アドレス払い出し契約のほうが絶対楽ですけどね。